# How to resize window in Java from a click (in this case, a button)?

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe

I was just wondering how (and if) this is possible. I read somewhere about an ActionEvent with resize window(int, int) but I wasn't sure if that was an appropriate way to handle it.

Edit: sorry this is in an GUI interface set up by JPanel

Comment: Best to before asking here simply try it and see what happens.

Comment: Generally I would not set a size for a window.  They are either 1) packed (smallest size needed to accommodate the components) 2) full-screen (e.g. for a v. pretty animation in a `JWindow`) 3) dragged to an exact size as specified by the user and/or their OS (e.g. if you expand the height of a window on Windows 7 far enough, it jumps to filling the maximum vertical screen size available).   So what is the advantage of offering a button to set the size of the GUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.setSize(200, 200);
        }
    });
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(button);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To resize to the smallest possible size(but not minimized), use frame.pack();
for changing the size, use frame.setSize(, );
If you want to minimize, maximize, etc., setState() is supposed to work, but I'm not sure about it

Comment: frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED); to minimize - yes it does work :)