# Changing the size of a jFrame on button click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm creating a "Presentation" on a jFrame as part of a project and need some help.
I have it starting as a 200, 200 size frame with a button in the middle that says "Let's Start"
then when you click on it, the size of the frame changes. When I click on the button you have to drag the window to make it the already defined size seen as the window stays the original 200 by 200 it doesn't open the window to 1335 by 675.

Here's my code.

```
package randomGUIs;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Presentation extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Presentation() {
    initComponents();

    startPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    startPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setText("Let's Start");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout startPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(startPanel);
    startPanel.setLayout(startPanelLayout);
    startPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        startPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(startPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(50, 50, 50)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(49, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    startPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        startPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(startPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(78, 78, 78)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(77, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(startPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,      javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(startPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    startPanel.setSize(new Dimension(1335, 675));
    startPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1335, 675));
    startPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1335, 675));

    jButton1.setVisible(false);

}                                        

public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Presentation().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JPanel startPanel;
```

}

I've tried using `startPanel.repaint();` with no luck.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use repaint cuz I think with simple action listener you can do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize window in Java from a click (in this case, a button)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966535/how-to-resize-window-in-java-from-a-click-in-this-case-a-button)

Comment: @KickButtowski The frame is getting re-sized just fine its just that I would like the frame to open as the defined sizes once the button is clicked

Comment: did you take a look at my link ?

Comment: I didnt understand what you want but...did you try startPanel.revalidate() ?

Comment: @KickButtowski, I took a look, didn't really see much that I haven't tried already.

Comment: *"When I click on the button you have to manually set the size of the frame."* Who is *"you"* and what is *"manually"*? When you click a button the action is done automatically.

Comment: @user1803551, You have to drag the screen to make the full jLabel/Frame show up. It just stays the 200 by 200.

Comment: What is *"drag the screen"*? The screen stays the same. *"make the full jLabel/Frame show up"* What `JLabel`? I don't see one in your code. If you want help you have the answer our requests for clarifications and be **very** precise.

Comment: @user1803551 Panel* my bad. I'll edit my whole question.

Comment: @user1803551, Here, this is my full code. http://tny.cz/4afc7c1c

Comment: Notify me when you finish rewriting the question.

Comment: @user1803551, Hows that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the frame size with this function.
In order to use this function you must include the relevant package.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
...
setSize(new Dimension(1320,220));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JFrame won't automagically resize itself unless you tell it to. Something like this:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        startPanel.setSize(new Dimension(1335, 675));
        startPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1335, 675));
        startPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1335, 675));

        frame.setSize(1335, 675);

        jButton1.setVisible(false);

    }
```

You could also use the pack() function of the JFrame class, depending on what you wanted to do.

Comment: Seen as I'm using Netbeans, it automatically creates a blank jFrame. Based on my code that I have linked in the question, could you show me an example?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (note: NOT your whole project!) and we'll go from there.

Comment: That isn't an MCVE. Just paste the code into your original question, as others have requested.

Comment: My bad, Not used to these type of things. Sorry for the hassle.